# C++ wrong result in multiplication of two unsigned long long integers

Tags: c++, unsigned-long-long-int

Consider the multiplication of the following `unsigned long long` integers:

```
unsigned long long a=4294967297;
unsigned long long b=4294967297;
cout<<a*b<<endl;
```

> 8589934593

I did not expect this answer. Instead I was expecting to get:

> 18446744065119617025

Note that, according to [this source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-160), the largest integer that can be represented by an `unsigned long long` is `18446744073709551615` (or in hexadecimal `0xffffffffffffffff`). This is by `8589934590` larger than my expected `18446744065119617025`, so that I was assuming this number could still be represented.

What is going on and how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

You guys are right, I was playing around with different numbers and confused the results of `4294967297` and `4294967295` squared. With `7` at the end it does overflow. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: a*b = 18446744082299486209 it is bigger than 18446744073709551615

Comment: Changing the types to `constexpr` and adding a result `constexpr unsigned long long c = a * b;` immediately warns that the operation causes an arithmetic overflow.

Comment: `4294967297` is `2^32 + 1` so `4294967297^2 > 2^64` does not fit into an `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing your math wrong:

```
slowpy3.8> 4294967297 * 4294967297
18446744082299486209
slowpy3.8> hex(_)
'0x10000000200000001'
slowpy3.8> 0xffffffffffffffff > 0x10000000200000001
False
slowpy3.8> math.log2(18446744082299486209)
64.0000000006718
slowpy3.8>
```